# How to delete a specific text showed in a ListView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have read this topic:
[how to delete a specific text / message showed in a ListView ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190813/how-to-delete-a-specific-text-message-showed-in-a-listview)

It works fine in winform (I have test it!) but in WPF it does not work.

I want to find a text of the firstnametxt in listview1 and compare it to Firstname Column items and if its true then delete the item (the row that contains the item)

But I do not know how to handle this in WPF.

Part of my code is like this:

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="listView1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<TextBox Name="firstnametxt" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="271,20,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" />
<Button Content="Add" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,242,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Click="button1_Click" />
<Button Content="Find" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Click="button2_Click" />
```

Code behind (C#):

```
public class Familiy
{
    public Familiy(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
    }
    private string firstname;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set { firstname = value; }
    }
    private string lastname;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    ///////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: How are you binding the list? Is it marked up in XAML or is it done in the code-behind?

Comment: Hi peter O , I bind the list through the xaml as i shown above and i add the items to the list like this : listView1.Items.Add(new Model("john","smith"));

Comment: The XAML doesn't show your binding. Or maybe I should say ***binding source***. Where are you getting the data for the list originally? Is it a `List` in the code-behind? Did you mark it up with an object data source?

Comment: I know your mean , you mean an arraylist, yes? I know but my code works fine with out the arraylist.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what structure is behind the list - your solution is quite easily solved by leveraging the structure that is bound to the list - and much less optimal to loop through items in the list.

Comment: i think you mean :   public ArrayList FamilyList(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
            list1.Add(new Family(firstname,lastname));
            return list1;
        }
  
  listView1.Items.Add(FamilyList("john","smith"));

Comment: i want to do the same thing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190813/how-to-delete-a-specific-text-message-showed-in-a-listview but in wpf.

Comment: I understand that, but don't personally feel that is a good approach and so I wanted to provide you with a more WPF'esq approach. WPF responds to data binding changes, as expected, and so changing the underlying structure will cause the UX to respond. Further, you can use a very simple LINQ query against the actual data source to do this rather than iterating through `ListViewItem` objects and casting stuff and all that. So, if you can post the code that binds the list, it would be helpful.

Comment: please help me with the sample code , do you want me to upload my project somewhere ?

Comment: Simply post the code that data binds the `ListView`.

Comment: i have posted all of my code. this code add item to listview1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to alter the ListBox's ItemSource wether it be a ItemList, List  or another collection Type this example uses a List of Familily.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Familiy> familiys = new List<Familiy>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        familiys.Add( new Familiy("FirstName1", "LastName1"));
        familiys.Add(new Familiy("FirstName2", "LastName2"));
        familiys.Add(new Familiy("FirstName3", "LastName3"));
        familiys.Add(new Familiy("FirstName4", "LastName4"));
        listView1.ItemsSource = familiys;

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        familiys.Remove(familiys.Find(delegate(Familiy f) { return f.FirstName == firstnametxt.Text; }));
        listView1.ItemsSource = "";
        listView1.ItemsSource = familiys;
    }
}
```

Comment: happy newyears :) be fresh :)

Comment: @SmartMan Glad to help. You have a happy new year yourself